.NET Core : trigger multiple methods to execute after x seconds
In C# in .NET Core Web App, I want to trigger a method to execute after a specific amount of time (seconds / minutes).
I need to "schedule" a large number of such methods executions (500-1000).
For example, below:

DoProcess(1) should execute in 1 seconds, DoProcess(2) in 2 seconds, DoProcess(3) in 3 seconds , etc...
DoProcess(2) should NOT to wait for DoProcess(1) to finish.

public async Task ProcessUsers()
{
    for (var delay = 1; delay < 500; delay++)
    {
        Task.Delay(delay).ContinueWith(async task =>await DoProcess(delay));
    }
}
    
public async Task DoProcess(int val)
{
    // Do some work that takes a few seconds.
    // work 123
}


Will that code work as I described?
Will each Task.Delay() create a new thread and (due to the large number of executions, 500) cause thread pool overload/exhaustion?
Can you suggest a better way to handle such requirement? I considered using some library like Quartz or Hangfire, but that seemed like an overkill.


I agree with Theodor that there are probably better ways to limit the resources used for processing. Still, if you wanna go that route, I found an interesting blog post here.
